# How to have javascript work on php loaded content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php file that loads a different form based on a identifier passed in with a GET request.

Everything works.... except my `Javascript/jQuery`.  Is there a way to re-load my `javascript` to get it to work on the form?

Or will I need to something else entirely ? like a template system?

Currently, when the page is being loaded by the browser it is commenting out my `Javascript` script tag that loads my `functions.js` file.  I'm assuming this is because it is because the code relies on a form and as the form hadn't been loaded yet, some kind of error forces the script to be commented out.

Comment: is your javascript <script> tag after the form, outside of the form?  I'm not sure what could be commenting out your Javascript, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rectify your problem in two ways:-

***1.*** Put you complete `javascript/jQuery` code at the bottom of the page (very last) inside (`<script></script>`)

Or

***2.*** Wrap your complete code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ...//your code ....});`

***Note:-***

***a.*** If you are trying to include an external `javascript/jQuery` file which have the custom code,then also include it at the bottom of the current page.

***b.*** Take care that proper jquery library (if needed) will added before your code

Comment: I was already doing number 2, so I additionally did number 1.  That get the js to not be commented out.  Thanks!

Comment: @daredevil1234  glad to help you. :):)

Comment: yeah, I'll mark it as soon as stackoverflow lets me.  Apparently there is a minimum amount of time that has to go by until I can accept an answer.  Never encountered that before.